# How to add validation on the form in flutter

Tags: flutter

I did manage to get no error for the code but cannot validate the form and show the error message. I have 3 component dart code which is the password, input field, and button. There is also one body dart in the library. ..................

I did manage to get no error for the code but cannot validate the form and show the error message. I have 3 component dart code which is the password, input field, and button. There is also one body dart in the library. ..................

```
import 'package:flutter_auth/Screens/Login/components/background.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/Screens/Login/components/uploadpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/components/rounded_input_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/components/rounded_password_field.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Background(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "LOGIN",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Username",
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.length == 0)
                  return "Please enter email";
                else if (!value.contains("@"))
                  return "Please enter valid email";
                else
                  return null;
              },
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            PasswordField(
              onSaved: (value) {},
            ),
            RoundedButton(
              text: "LOGIN",
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  goBackToPreviousScreen(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home Page"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.upload_file,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => uploadpage()),
                  );
                } // do something
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.purple[400],
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    goBackToPreviousScreen(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Logout')),
            ),
          )
        ]));
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of how Forms work:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = new GlobalKey();

  String formFieldValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              validator: (input) {
                if (input.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please type something';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (input) => formFieldValue = input,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: submitForm,
              child: Text(
                'Submit'
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  submitForm() {
    final formState = formKey.currentState;
    if (formState.validate()) {
      formState.save();
      // then do something
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the validator does not get called automatically. You have to call it manually onPressed of a button or something.

Here you need to wrap your column in Form widget and give it a key. Onpressed you need to validate it by calling key.currentState.validate()

```
    final _formreg = GlobalKey<FormState>();
        Form(key:_formreg, child:Column(children:
                   [RoundedInputField() ]
               ));
RaisedButton(onPressed:()=> {
a=_formreg.currentState.validate();
} )
```

a is a boolean value

Answer (score 0):

You can use package [wc_form_validators](https://pub.dev/packages/wc_form_validators) and read its documentation, it will help you to ease and fix your problem.